# mySQL recursive delete fails for large tables (ON DELETE CASCADE)

Tags: mysql, innodb, cascade

I have a very commonly used table schema to save trees:

```
id
parentId
name
```

where the `parentId` is set as a foriegn key and points to `id` and is set `ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE`. The whole thing is working fine as expected **until I try to delete nodes which have childs upto the depth of 40-50** i.e. when the CASCADE statement recursivley runs for 40-50 times. At this point I get this error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tbl332`.`data`, CONSTRAINT `data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `data` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I am unable to find why it is so? Any workaround?

Here is the schema:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=129 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data`
--

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `pid`, `name`, `date`) VALUES
(108, NULL, 'n1', '2014/07/26 14:08:08'),
(109, 108, 'n1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:11'),
(110, 109, 'n1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:13'),
(111, 110, 'n1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:15'),
(112, 111, 'n1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:16'),
(113, 112, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:17'),
(114, 113, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:18'),
(115, 114, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:18'),
(116, 115, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:20'),
(117, 116, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:21'),
(118, 117, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:22'),
(119, 118, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:23'),
(120, 119, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:24'),
(121, 120, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:25'),
(122, 121, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:26'),
(123, 122, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:28'),
(124, 123, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:29'),
(125, 124, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:31'),
(126, 125, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:33'),
(127, 126, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:35'),
(128, 127, 'n1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1', '2014/07/26 14:08:35');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `data`
--
ALTER TABLE `data`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `data` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**[FAIL]** And try to execute this, it fails:

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE id = 108
```

**[SUCCEED]** But this one succeeds:

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE id = 120
```

Comment: Can you post a sample table w data or otherwise make a SQL fiddle? This seems like an interesting problem

Comment: @WebChemist I have updated question with schema!

Comment: This is shortcoming (a bug in my opinion) of MySQL's foreign key implementation. Unlike most other DBMS MySQL checks the constraint for each row while deleting the row, instead of checking the constraint once the _statement_ is finished. Therefore the delete fails. There is nothing you can do about except for disabling the FK (or using a DBMS that does this correctly).