# Switching from MySQL to SQLServer: difficulty level?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've switched building anything with an UI to C#. Up to now I've been native C++ only. And I've only worked with MySQL and SQLite in terms of databases.

I'm tempted to switch to a Microsoft only Stack as I imagine C# + SQLServer get along better.

So I set up a LocalDB instance to switch some tables over from MySQL to get a feel of things. Obviously, within 15 minutes of using SQLServer I managed to get the expected WTF moments:

1. No such thing as `IF NOT EXISTS`. You need to wrap the `CREATE TABLE` in a crazy `IF` to replicate the functionality. Same for `CONSTRAINTS`.
2. `UNIQUE` columns take `NULL` into consideration so you can have only one `NULL`. You need to setup a special `NON-CLUSTERED UNIQUE` with a `WHERE` to replicate expected functionality that says `NULL`s don't exist and you can't compare them.
3. No such thing as `INSERT IGNORE`. You set the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON` flag on the actual `UNIQUE` keys.
4. No `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE` for `PRIMARY KEY` foreign keys in same table. I understand you don't UPDATE primary keys that often, but no `DELETE CASCADE`?

SAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE t0 
(
    id   INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
        references t0 (id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

1. I tried to use SQLServer years ago but could not find how to paginate results *(aside from `TOP`)*. Now I see they added `OFFSET` + `NEXT` to do that.

*This is only 15 minutes of testing.*

The question is:

Is it like this the whole way? Is Microsoft really going their own way with SQLServer too? *(they've done it with IE for over a decade)* Not that I expect full query level compatibility but seriously... how hard is it to have a `INSERT IGNORE` or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` or treat `NULL` as void not as an actual value?

Can anyone that moved over share some hints for a smoother transition or should I just stick to `MySQL`, which I've been friends for a while... but is GPL?

Comment: Among all the DBMSes I've worked with, it's MySQL the one that definitively has more WTF moments, esp. all its "features" regarding data integrity—I'm sure you're spoilt by it. In any case, though I understand your grief, I'm afraid this question is too wide and subjective to make a good fit at Stack Overflow.

Comment: "*no on update cascade*" - SQL Server sure does support that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ec0b/1  Btw: if you are looking for an open source alternative to MySQL which is not GPL you should seriously consider Postgres

Comment: nr 2) seems perfectly fine to me. nr 5) you could do that years ago also. you just have an easier syntax now

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added an example.

Comment: You might be able to declare such a foreign key in MySQL but you can't really delete from that table due to MySQL's (broken in my eyes) constraint handling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932039

Comment: [You're right, you should migrate from MySQL](http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else).

Comment: @ta.speot.is Good read.

Comment: The reason you're getting WTF moments is that you've been doing it wrong all these years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really difficult. 
SQL server has a lot of extra stuff that MySQL doesn't have. 
CTEs, writable CTEs, recursive CTEs, etc.

Your tables, you can easily re-create/migrate using a tool like nHibernate or entity framework with database first. 
Of course, it's the million little things that you need to fix manually (like unique indexes).
You can actually create a filtered unique index (`where your_column is not null`)
Also, SQL-Server doesn't truncate overly lengthy strings for you, which may require some ugly application code plumbing. 
Manual plumbing will also be required if you use autoincrement ids.
But the main problem are your views and your procedures. 
That's pretty much manual work, and thus time-consuming and error-prone.
Also, in SQL-Server, you can pretty much forget scalar functions, because they are far too slow in pretty much any respect (they are useful for a few things).

The problem is mainly to use the abstract classes in `System.Data.Common` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient` in your application code.
So when you have an application that uses MySQL.Data.MySqlClient, or an application that uses System.Data.SqlClient, and you want to switch either from or to SQL-server, then you'll have to re-write your application code as well, not just the SQL.
That's why you should always use `System.Data.Common`, instead of `"Namespace of the day".SqlConnection`

As for paging, SQL-Server 2012+ supports the ANSI-SQL paging method:

```
SELECT
     [TransactionID]
    ,[ProductID]
    ,[ReferenceOrderID]
    ,[ReferenceOrderLineID]
    ,[TransactionDate]
    ,[TransactionType]
    ,[Quantity]
    ,[ActualCost]
    ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Production].[TransactionHistoryArchive]
ORDER BY [TransactionID]
OFFSET 5001 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Before SQL-server 2012, you had to use CTE's:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT
         [TransactionID]
        ,[ProductID]
        ,[ReferenceOrderID]
        ,[ReferenceOrderLineID]
        ,[TransactionDate]
        ,[TransactionType]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[ActualCost]
        ,[ModifiedDate]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ActualCost DESC) AS rn 
    FROM [Production].[TransactionHistoryArchive]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn BETWEEN @min_row AND @max_row
```

To create a table if it does not exists, you need to put the table-create code into dynamic SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[T_Verbs]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Verbs](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Infinitive] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [FirstPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [SecondPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ThirdPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Singular] [bit] NULL,
    [Plural] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END



IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[T_Verbs]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Verbs](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Infinitive] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [FirstPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [SecondPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ThirdPerson] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Singular] [bit] NULL,
    [Plural] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
');
END


GO
```

As to switching to SQL-Server: Why ? 
It's just an overly expensive licensing nightmare.
You're far better of with MySQL.
However, if you need things like data-integrity, MySQL & ANSI compliant paging and CTEs, arrays, associative arrays, JSON, etc., I'd move over to PostgreSQL instead.

In my opinion, SQL-server is only really good when you need the business intelligence features it provides (don't expect the BI web edition to be really compatible with anything else than InternetExplorer [QuirksMode, by the way]), or when you have a lot of clients that use SQL-server and don't want something else.

Comment: I'm very used to write queries by hand. Seen some EF benchmarks and they don't look great. **I think I'll look into PostgreSQL indeed.** Their array data types look good.

Comment: **BOLD** you're last paragraph, it sums it all up.

Comment: @CodeAngry: Just to clarify: I didn't say you should use EF or nhibernate. Actually quite to the contrary, to say performance is lousy would be flattery for those ORMs.  What I meant is you can use these tools to migrate the table schema to SQL-Server for you. Then you can use SSMS to let it create the table-create scripts. Of course, you need to check the results manually (don't belive for a moment they will do everything correctly, as you discovered with the unique indexes for example). Another such thing is inserts with autoids, btw., FYI.

Comment: @CodeAngry: Yep, the arrays are really cool. Another thing to look at is hstore (associative arrays, it's in contrib, so you need to enable the extension first).